# Type 'Framework.Controls.XpProgressBar' is not defined

Tags: vb.net

I have to understand existing code written in VB.net.
In one of file I am getting error

> "Type 'Framework.Controls.XpProgressBar' is not defined"

.Visual studio 2005,2008 and 2010 installed on my machine.

Code below :

```
Me.XpProgressBar1 = New Framework.Controls.XpProgressBar
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the XpProgressBar component included in your project?

Comment: I'm assuming it refers to this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11839/Fully-Customizable-XP-Progress-Bar-with-examples

Comment: I have no idea about "XpProgressBar component'.

Comment: i am not familiar with XpProgressBar; I simply found it with a search. If I had to guess, I'd advise that the project you are working on used this component, however it was not included with the project when you obtained it. You can either ask the person who created the project, or try downloading the component from the link above and including it in the project yourself.